# Запятая в обороте "братан верный как пёс"

Tags: орфография

Перед союзом `"как"` запятая не ставится, если оборот входит в состав фразеологизма.

`"Верный как пёс"` по всей видимости является фразеологизмом.

Тогда во фразе `"У меня есть братаны, верные как псы"` после `"верные"` запятая не ставится. Это так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on which grammatical role you are using *как псы* in.

If you mean your have buddies who are very loyal to you, and *верные как псы* is just a synonym to *очень верные*, you should not use a comma here.

Compare:

> Черные как ночь (*= очень чёрные*), могучие «абердино-ангусы», под ними земля дрожала, до тонны весом быки.

If you mean your buddies are loyal to you in a doggish way and *верные как псы* is a synonym to *по-собачьи верные*, you should not use a comma either.

Compare:

> Японец с палкой вдруг зашипел как змея (*= по-змеиному*) и что было сил треснул Петькиного япошку по голове.

Finally, if you mean that your buddies are loyal to you as dogs are loyal to their master (in some way which you are probably going to describe), i.e. it's neither a simile nor a manner, but a true comparison, you should use a comma.